# How to toggle visibility of a series on a chart in Microsoft Forms?

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-forms

I am making a Microsoft Forms program in Visual Basic for a college project. As part of this I have a chart with a number of series on it. How would I go about changing one of these series to be not visible on the chart? I have tried to read the documentation on the Chart component but have not found a solution

How I created the series:

```
GraphDisplay.Series.Add(Country1Name)
```

Where GraphDisplay is the name of my chart, and Country1Name is the name of the series

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted some of your code, specifically how the series is added to the chart, but assuming you have a [Series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series?view=netframework-4.8) object, this is generally how you would hide the series. Change the [Enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.enabled?view=netframework-4.8) property to False

```vb
Dim s As New Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series()
s.Enabled = False
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.enabled?view=netframework-4.8):

> Gets or sets a flag that indicates whether the series will be visible on the rendered chart.